# Handling many combinations in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Following regex: `((?:ba*)|(?:ab*))`

Matches `"ab ba"`, that is the word can be ba or ab. The order doesnt matter.
However, what if I wanted to add a `"c"` as well? Order should matter but that means I would have to write something like this:

`(((?:ba*)|(?:a*b))\b|\b((?:bc*)|(?:c*b))) etc...`

So basically all these combinations should match:

```
ab ba ac ca ca bc cb
```

Are there any clean techniques for handling such scenario without the regex becoming too long?

**Note:** I wont accept answers using dot (.) character class for whatever reason that may be.

Please note that each letter can only appear once in each combination. For example: a{1}b{1}

Comment: Are the `a`, `b` and `c` placeholders for multicharacter strings? If these are single symbols, you may use a character class, [`[abc]+`](https://regex101.com/r/ErVzON/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I forgot to say that I want to limit the amount of single characters. For example a{1}.

Comment: You may set limits with negative lookaheads: [`\b(?!a\w*a)[abc]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ErVzON/2).  However, the pattern may grow when using them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  indeed but after checking your regex: acbbb would also match where I only want to match a group of 2 unique characters in the set mentioned (abc)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed but try typing abc.

Comment: Well, for me `abc|acb|bac|cab|bca|cba` looks way more clear and short enough

Comment: @smnbbrv what if we have 10 per group? : ) Regex will get really long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match 2-letter words that consist of unique letters from a predefined set you may use

```
/\b([abc])(?!\1)[abc]\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ErVzON/4)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `([abc])` - Capturing group 1 matching either `a`, `b` or `c`
- `(?!\1)[abc]` - `a`, `b` or `c` that are not equal to the preceding character (due to the `\1` backreference)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

JS example:

```js
var chset = "[abc]";
var rx = new RegExp("\\b(" + chset + ")(?!\\1)" + chset + "\\b", "g");
var s = "ab cc aa bb ca ab ba ac ca ca bc cb";
var results = s.match(rx);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: It looks simple but it wasnt obvious at first. I never thought of using a combination of negative lookahead and backreferencing to achieve this.